# Auto UUID Creation on PostgreSQL COPY Command

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm copying some data into a postgres database, and the CSV files do not have UUIDs. Currently the schema for the DB looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
   customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   customer_age INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The COPY statement is as follows:

```
COPY customers FROM '/usr/app/data/customers.csv' HEADER csv;
```

And the CSV file is shaped like this:

```
customer_name,customer_age
"Peter",12
"Sam",13
```

How can I automatically create the UUID for the customers data on the COPY command if it doesn't already exist in the CSV file? Currently this COPY command fails because it expects the customer_name row to be the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! This one is straightforward, you must specify the columns you're copying over:

```
COPY items (customer_name, customer_age) FROM '/usr/app/data/customers.csv' HEADER csv;
```